# Set page limit for category and don't allow to change it

Tags: category, pager

I want to set specific page size for one category, I do this in Custom Layout Update this way:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="addPagerLimit"><limit>2</limit></action>
    <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>2</limit></action>
    <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>2</limit></action>
</reference>
```

It works as intended - default limit is 2, but when I change the limit in other category (e.g. to 9) it is now current limit.
Probably limits are stored in users session.

I would like to override current limit in this particular category, to be 2 all the time. I tried methods `setCurrentLimit` and `setLimit` but both doesn't work.

Comment: Your solution is not perfect, because of hardcoded category IDs, but still better than mine. I just tweaked it to use Custom Layout Update xml and is perfect.

Comment: i didnt say you need to acxept my answer in fact. If you feel, your answer is better, please accept yours itself. second my extension is intended for developers and not for merchants. its an experiment. I think you at least study how can do this in better way and that is what I want. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an extension for this. You can ***[find the extension here](https://github.com/progammer-rkt/magento-set-page-size)***. It is absolutely free.

The advantage of my module over yours is, it does not use any rewrites. In Magento, it is better to avoid rewrites if possible. So have a look on my extension and make an idea and modify as per your need. I think in your case, you can directly use my extension.

Also you can find more details on [how can we limit page size in my blog](http://rajeev-k-tomy.blogspot.in/2014/07/set-page-size-for-particular-category.html).

Answer (score 3):

I did it by overriding `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar` and creating method `setCurrentLimitValue`:

```
public function setCurrentLimitValue($limit)
{
    $this->setData('_current_limit', $limit);
}
```

Then in Custom Layout Update for category I added:

```
<action method="setCurrentLimitValue"><limit>2</limit></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **best free magento extension** available on **magento marketplace**.

https://marketplace.magento.com/invigoratesystems-module-productsizecategorywise.html

it allows admin to set category wise page limit.